# Trigger on markers

Tags: after-effects-expressions

Can someone please break down this small bit of code for me,  at a highlevel. Particularly the part `n=n-1`, I haven't worked out why we minus 1 from the marker here.

Thanks

```
    n = marker.nearestKey(time).index; 
 if(time < marker.key(n).time){
  n=n-1;
 }
 if(n==0){
  n=1
 }
 t=time-marker.key(n).time;
 thisProperty.valueAtTime(t)
```